# facebook giving an error when putting status on live

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am just filling up all the info which facebook need while creating the Facebook login app with key hash and all but when I am putting status in live mode it's showing me some errors you can check in the screenshot please https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvb1N.png

Comment: Sounds like Facebook is trying to verify the app store URL is reachable, but that test fails. Did you only very recently configure your app in the play store? Then it might simply be that it takes a little time, before Google has fully processed the changes, and makes the app store page publicly available.

Comment: Update privacy policy url , terms & conditions url, data deletion information in settings.